# GIT Extensions - Push - "fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly"

Tags: git, git-extensions

I am trying to push a self-hosted server repository to Git using Git extensions. I can do it OK using the command line but using Git extensions it comes up with the message:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe push --recurse-submodules=check "Specflow.Infrastructure.git" master:master
Done
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I tried all of these combinations for the repository:

```
ssh://username@192.168.0.1/path/to/repository.git
ssh://192.168.0.1/path/to/repository.git
username@192.168.0.1/path/to/repository.git
192.168.0.1/path/to/repository.git
```

But same problem. However when I run the command mentioned in the error:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe push --recurse-submodules=check "Specflow.Infrastructure.git" master:master
```

It works!

I read something about setting the `HOME` environment variable to be your home directory. I check that this directory does contain the `.ssh` folder and it does, with the correct details. So I set the `HOME` variable and restarted my machine. Same problem!

The other answers to this questions are for similar but different scenarios where a specific error message is produced between the words "Done" and "Fatal" hence the need for this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this same problem.  I fixed it by going into the Settings -> Settings in Git Extensions.  I then clicked on the SSH tab and  selected openSSH in the  "Specify SSH client to use".  I originally had it set to PuTTY.